# Is $k[x,xy] \subseteq k[x,y]$ a flat ring extension?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.

> Is $k[x,xy] \subseteq k[x,y]$ a flat ring extension?

I guess that the answer is no? Though I am not sure how to prove this.
Perhaps applying [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562243/criterion-for-proving-flatness) criterion (showing it is not satisfied?) will help.

Any comments and hints are welcome!

Comment: I'm very rusty with this, but I think the second criterion [in WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module#Flat_ring_extensions) bites. We have $R=k[x,t]$ with $t=xy$ and $S=k[x,y]=R[u]/f$, where  $f(u)=xu-t$. The coefficients of $f$ are $x$ and $-t$, and they don't generate the unit ideal. I'm afraid I need to think about turning this to a counterexample violating the definition.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you very much. I guess that you are right.

Comment: This corresponds to a blow-up, and blow-ups are a typical example of non-flat map. The ideal $xk[x,y]$ contracts to a maximal ideal violating the going-down property (or @JyrkiLahtonen' comment as $t,x$ don't form a regular sequence in $S$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $A=k[x,xy]$ and $B=k[x,y]$. (Notice that $A$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring over $k$ in two variables.)
We have an exact sequence $0\to A/xA\stackrel{xy\cdot}\to A/xA$.
Assuming that $B$ is $A$-flat and tensoring by this we get that $0\to B/xB\stackrel{xy\cdot}\to B/xB$ is exact. But this is the zero map, so $B=xB$, a contradiction.